# Spotlight search returns no results on iOS (intermittently)

Tags: spotlight

I'm on 8.0.2 but it happened on 8.0.0 too.

[image: empty spotlight results]

Spotlight just won't show anything no matter what I type.

Comment: Possibly related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240587/spotlight-search-on-ios-not-showing-options-to-search-web-maps-app-store-unless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Send yourself an email from the iPhone to your iPhone email address**

Yes seriously. I know that sounds absurd, but sending your iOS device an email actually makes Spotlight search start working again. All you need to do is send yourself an email to whatever mail account is setup on the iOS device, and once the new email is detected by iOS Mail app (as indicated by a Notification or the new mail chime), suddenly Spotlight works again.

Comment: Doesn't last, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I have this to they only resolution so far is either go old turn off and on again or reboot then seems to work again. Do you use other keyboards too? because I thought it was linked to this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem exists in 8.1.2 as well.

When this sporadic behaviour appears even a reboot of the device will not always fix this.

The only thing that helped so far is waiting a few minutes and then spotlight suddenly magically works again properly.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything close at http://openradar.appspot.com/ so it seems this issue is quite infrequent

EDIT: Yes I got an gif keyboard installed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with iOS 8.3. The only thing that seemed to help was to reboot the phone. Then search results were as they should be. This doesn't last, however, and needs to be done again after a while. I wish it would be fixed, as it seems this has been ongoing for a long time and through many operating systems.